# How to know when is end of message in serial communication?

Tags: c#, serial-port, microcontroller

I'm using C# to send a message to my microcontroller and I want to know if there is a way to know when is the end of message? I saw on some discussion that it is last character 0xff, but it doesn't work.

Comment: it's your uC, decide your own protocol to finish communication. You may use [EOT - End Of Transmission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) (ASCII 4), for example.

Comment: Agree with @AdrianoRepetti, you have to look for EndOfTransmission character on the end of your message. But this will also depends on how was your microcontroller programmed. Maybe the programmer decided to use different termination character than the one you would usually use...

Comment: Each end of the serial link needs to agree on the protocol.  First you have to establish the character framing: baud rate, number of bits, parity etc.  You have to establish the type of data and the message format.  Text data using ASCII will typically use a control character to end the line, usually with a carriage return or newline.  The POSIX line discipline handler facilitates this type of messages.  A binary message format can be almost anything you want so long as it works.  Some protocols (e.g. Modbus) use deadtime between messages to indicate frames.

Comment: **EOT** is not appropriate for terminating just a message.  There's **EOM** for that.  Ending a transmission means the sender is signing off and not sending any more.

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on the data transmitted. If it is just text data @AdrianoRepetti 's suggestion will work. If the data is both text and binary you can't use ASCII 0x4 since binary data can use ASCII 0x4 as part of the data stream. Instead you can probably use HW flow control, but this requires SW on the uC and on the host to honor the flow control.